# scala - How to run a task every day a 11PM

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

With playframework, I'm trying to run a function to send a mail every day at 11PM but I don't know how to do.
I found many answers accros the internet but I haven't managed to adapt with Scala language, do you have  a example of tutorial ?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Akka Scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/scheduler.html) and [Play! Scheduled jobs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.x/jobs#scheduling)

EDIT:

I'll personally prefer Play! scheduler which uses cron. So in the example (copy/paste), you could create a Scala class similar to this:

```
import play.jobs.*;

/** Fire at 12pm (noon) every day **/ 
@On("0 0 12 * * ?")
public class Bootstrap extends Job {

    public void doJob() {
        Logger.info("Maintenance job ...");
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Really a link-only answer - copy in the bit about cron-expressions, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use akka quartz scheduler https://github.com/enragedginger/akka-quartz-scheduler